# How to do data migration of Cassandra from one keyspace to another keyspace?

Tags: cassandra, migration

I created an old keyspace in Cassandra cluster but found the definition of its "comparator" is wrong, so I have to recreate a new keyspace and do data migration. Is there any tool to do data migration? or I have to program with Thrift client read all data from old keyspace and write them to new keyspace? Any suggestions or code snippets is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

This is a commun question, and I think it has been asked before here.
You can use the `COPY` command in C*. 
You will find more details here http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/ways-to-move-data-tofrom-datastax-enterprise-and-cassandra

Answer (score 2):

We can do it using `COPY` command in cql. Using `COPY` command we can save table data to *.csv* file and back to a table from *.csv* file. But, the better approach will be to write a program to read from table and write it to another table because importing from csv may fail if the table contains collection column types like `list<text>`, `map<text, text>`, `set<text>`.

Eg :-
To copy table data from table to .csv file :-

```
COPY keyspace1.table1 (column1, column2) TO 'path/to/file/keyspace1_table1.csv';
```

To copy csv data from file to a table :-

```
COPY keyspace2.table1 (column1, column2) FROM 'path/to/file/keyspace1_table1.csv';
```

Refer [Cassandra migration tool](https://www.smartcat.io/blog/2015/cassandra-migration-tool/)